# How to fetch online Facebook friends in iPhone using Graph API?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to fetch the Facebook user's online friends using Graph API but I am not able to find any help from the net.

I am able to fetch the user's friends using Graph API but i want to know who are currently online, also more info about the user's friends like the image URL, date of birth, etc.

I am only able to fetch the user's friend's id and name using the following line of code

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible using the graph API.

According to a [facebook dev forum thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=226298) on the subject there are ways to do this by calling a php script that the website itself uses in AJAX requests, or using XMPP

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
    NSArray* resultArray = [result allObjects];

    NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
    result = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
    result = [result objectAtIndex:0];

    [self.label setText:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```